# Creating a thread in a shared library constructor

Tags: c, linux, pthreads

I want to create a thread inside one of my LD_PRELOADed shared library constructor. I currently have the following.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <unistd.h>

void* worker(void* t) {
  sleep(1);
  printf("Running worker..\n");
  return NULL;
}

__attribute__((constructor))
void spawn() {
  pthread_t t;
  printf("[INFO] In the constructor..\n");

  int rc = pthread_create(&t, NULL, worker, (void *)NULL);
  if (rc){
    printf("[FATAL] Failed spawn the thread..\n");
    exit(-1);
  }
}
```

But the thread doesn't seem to be running even though the constructor gets invoked. Is spawning threads before main not recommended? I tried both gcc and g++.

Comment: Post an [MCVE]. Why tag c++ ?

Comment: It works for me. Assuming what you posted is in bar.c, with a trivial main which just sleeps for a while in foo.c, `cc -o foo foo.c && cc -pthread -fPIC -shared -o bar.so bar.c && LD_PRELOAD=./bar.so ./foo`

Comment: I'm not sure if it should work, but it often isn't a great idea for libraries to create threads without being asked.

Comment: Wow. I totally misread this question. Good thing I didn't write anything that would make me look like an idiot. Any way you can keep `rc` around to monitor its status?

Comment: Okay. It seems to be working now. I *do* feel like an idiot now. Looks like some cached object file was cause of the issue. But in general I wanted to know if this was recommended. And it seems not? I am guessing this is not standardized behavior.. @Stargateur I have removed the c++ tag now. I included that since I also tried with g++.

Comment: @user4581301 I guess I could. Earlier I wasn't seeing the output from the thread when the application ran.

Comment: You can do all sorts of things before `main`, but they can be troublesome to debug. Very annoying when a program crashes before you can start stepping it with a debugger.

Answer (score 0):

Your main thread is not waiting for thread to complete work. add pthread_join after pthread_create.

As I haven't used **attribute**((constructor)) anytime is past, I can't much comment on it, but  you may add pthread_join in **attribute**((destructor)).

Comment: Problem with this answer: The worker thread being created is in a library loading function. The actual `main` function comes later. For a non-trivial example thread, this answer would block entry into `main` and a start to the library user's code. It would very easily cause a deadlock.